# More review options?

Tags: feature-request, answers, reviews

Is there a way to add more options to the review stuff. A lot of the times the problem with the answer is that it needs to be expanded on, rather than any of the current options given, or perhaps a way to mark something as a Low Quality answer and possibly allow the answerer to mark it that way themselves...

I know that personally I might know the general answer, but not want to go into detail or go do the research to answer it in a way that I would consider a good answer. In some cases this results in someone not getting an answer at all which from a questioners perspective isn't something that like happening. An answer, however low quality it is, so long as it is accurate, is better than no answer.

So would it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is one option for you: downvote. By downvoting, you consider that ok, the answer is somehow valid and does not need to be deleted. But yet, would greatly benefit from a bit of work. So you downvote it.

A possible exception to it, are one-liners/single sentence answers. For me that amounts to no answer at all.

And to answer your specific question, to my knowledge, those options are valid throughout the network and cannot be personnalised on a site per site basis.